# Error while installing dependencies for RVIZ

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fuerte on
Ubuntu 10.04

Few weeks back rviz was running on my system, but then now, it is showing some problems.

The console output:

```
sai@sai-desktop:~/fuerte_workspace$ rosdep install rviz
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rviz: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [libogre-dev]
sai@sai-desktop:~/fuerte_workspace$
```

roswtf doesnot show any error.

rviz is in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

I will first install the dependencies for rviz, then rosmake and rosrun it.

I did what you said in the answer...
it resulted in

```
sai@sai-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-visualization
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  ros-fuerte-visualization: Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry (= 1.8.2-s1344793584~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-fuerte-laser-pipeline (= 1.4.4-s1344799073~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-fuerte-robot-model (= 1.8.1-s1344897363~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42100/error-while-installing-dependencies-for-rviz/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2012-08-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-23**:
Try `sudo apt-get update` and maybe `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to upgrade all packages before installing ros-fuerte-visualization.

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-08-23**:
I executed both of them and they did not give any errors. Still the reos-fuerte-visualization is resulting in same error...

**Comment by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on 2012-08-23**:
I have found many such dependency error when I used Fuerte with ubuntu 10.04. However, after I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 there were no problems and all the dependencies were properly installed. Modifying your ros package source to that of precise(12.04) in your software sources may help.

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-08-24**:
Thanks, I will try that and report it here...:)

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-08-24**:
Yes it worked when UBUNTU 12.04 was installed. Thank you so much for the suggestions..

**Comment by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on 2012-08-25**:
tht sounds good :) all the best with your work :) mayb u can upvote my answer so that others feel it the most reliable comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Normally, you install rviz debian package:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-visualization
```

That pulls in all dependencies already, so you don't need to run rosdep or rosmake, just `rosrun rviz rviz`.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-09-02**:
Yes..it worked on ubuntu 10.04 initially but later it didnt work and showed up some errors. When I installed ubuntu12.04, there were no errors..